# Firebase Security Rules with wildcards (Permission denied even though access is granted)

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Below is my firestore database

[image]

The message subcollection look like this:

[image]

Below is my security rules.

```
match /channels/{channelID=**} {
    allow read: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.participants;
    allow write: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.participants;
```

However, when I try to listen to the message documents in the message collection with the code below

```
firestore.collection('channels').doc(channelId).collection('messages').snapshots()
```

I received the following error:

> flutter: [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have
> permission to execute the specified operation.

> 8.3.0 - [Firebase/Firestore][I-FST000001] Listen for query at channels/RILvs2HvV8OiYrsk0W0ZxhxaU8H3-EpPAVCmuYnTWGxvASNk5rgUHTe63/messages
> failed: Missing or insufficient permissions.

I have allowed access to all the subcollections and documents with =** in the security rules, but I'm not sure why is permission still denied? Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You are trying to access channel ID: `"RILvs2HvV8OiYrsk0W0ZxhxaU8H3-EpPAVCmuYnTWGxvASNk5rgUHTe63"` as in the error. In your screenshot the ID starts with `Gmf..` Can you `print(channelId)` before the query and check if its valid?

Comment: Hi @Dharmaraj, yup, I screenshot it as an example. But I've reuploaded the screenshot to make it clearer.

Comment: Hi @Dharmaraj, I've added a screenshot of the message subcollection and document above for more clarity

Comment: @scottlee Add `sub collection` name to your path. `match /channels/{channelID=**}/messages/{messageId=**}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in you are trying to read documents in messages sub-collection and so `resource.data` will be data of those messages documents and not the channel document. The `participants` array however is present in the channel document so yry using `get()` instead to read that document's data as shown below.

```js
match /channels/{channelId}/messages/{messageId} {
    allow read, write: if request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/channels/$(channelId)).data.participants;
}
```

If you use recursive wildcard here then value of `channelId` would be `"/RILvs2HvV8OiYrsk0W0ZxhxaU8H3-EpPAVCmuYnTWGxvASNk5rgUHTe63/messages/JR12q13OvpYISJmHilcq"` (in this example) but the path in `get()` should be just `/channels/{channelId}`

Comment: @scottlee this doesn't matter if you are using listener on client side. You need to read the channel document to check participants array therefore you use `get()` in the security rules. This has nothing to do with your code on client side. Please try copying the rules above. Essentially when using `resourcee.data`, the rules will try to look for participants array in the messages documents which is undefined.

Comment: hmm, the same error still persists even after using the rules.

Comment: @scottlee please try updated answer. There was a typo `channelID` instead of `channelId` and maybe you would have to use complete path instead of recursive wildcards